# Remove extension .html and reedirect to www. from HTCACCES

Tags: html, .htaccess

I am trying to delete the .html extension in all of my web pages, and redirect all of my pages to www. on the htcacces, but I don't know how to do that. I've tried this but it only works the for the redirect:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gangatravel.es$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http://www.gangatravel.es/" [R=301,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /notFound.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Answer (score 0):

For removing html file, you must use below code:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.html [L]
```

and for force www, use:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yoursite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yoursite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```